# removing Figure text in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I insert an image in Rmarkdown I see "Figure #:" below the image.

How do you get rid of the "Figure:" text?

for example here is my code

```
![my caption](C:/mypath/myimage.png)
```

and the image appear with "Figure 1: my caption" below it. I just want the caption to the "my caption"

I looked here http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options  and fig.lp seems like it might be a solution but when I include that in the header like:

```
---
title: "My Title"
output: pdf_document
fig.lp: ('';character)
---
```

the "Figure :" still shows up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

All you have to do is add a backslash to the end of the line:

```
![my caption](C:/mypath/myimage.png)\
```

Comment: This removes the caption for only one single image while maintaining it for the rest. Nice! However, slightly different from what OP asked for though.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `fig_caption` option in the header, like so:

```
---
title: "My Title"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: false
---
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a hidden code chunk at the beginning of the document.

````
```{r echo = F}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.lp = '')
```
````

Comment: I was not able to get this to work, however, for a PDF output, you can always use the latex command: \includegraphics{myimage.png}